# To Be - 变成 vs 当

Tags: meaning-in-context, verbs

In the song 学猫叫 (Xue Mao Jiao) are two lines that seem to have [similar](https://asianeuphoria.com/2018/10/10/lyrics-xiao-pan-pan-and-xiao-feng-feng-learn-to-meow/) [English](https://translate.google.com/?sl=zh-CN&tl=en&text=*%20%E6%88%91%E6%83%B3%E8%A6%81%E5%BD%93%E4%BD%A0%E7%9A%84%E5%B0%8F%E7%8C%AB%E7%8C%AB%20%20%0A*%20%E6%83%B3%E8%A6%81%E5%8F%98%E6%88%90%E4%BD%A0%E7%9A%84%E7%8C%AB%20&op=translate) [translations](https://www.echinesesong.com/xue-mao-jiao-%E5%AD%A6%E7%8C%AB%E5%8F%AB-learn-to-meow-lyrics-%E6%AD%8C%E8%A9%9E-with-pinyin-by-xiao-pan-pan-%E5%B0%8F%E6%BD%98%E6%BD%98-xiao-feng-feng-%E5%B0%8F%E5%B3%B0%E5%B3%B0/):

- 我想要当你的小猫猫 - "I want to be your cat"
- 想要变成你的猫 - "I want to be your cat"

Do 当 and 变成 mean the same thing in this context, or has my English translation lost nuances that make the words different somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

当 = be (in a role/ in a position)

变成 = change into/ become (something)

- 我想要**当**你的小猫猫 - "I want to **be** your little kitten"
- 我想要**变成**你的猫 - "I want to **become** your cat"

The translator didn't follow the lyrics word for word

Answer (score 1):

想要**变成**你的猫 - "I want to **become/change into** your cat"

Comment: "pussycat" sounds nicer!